# On the essential ideal of a Lie algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras, noncommutative-algebra

everyone. I'm studying somethings about Lie algebras and I have a simple problem (apparently), but I don't get to prove.

Question: How to prove that intersection of essential ideals of a semiprime Lie algebra is again an essential ideal?

I have proved this result only for finite intersection. I accept any suggestion. Thanks a lot.

A Lie algebra $L$ is said to be semiprime if for every non-zero ideal $I$ of $L$, $[I,I]\neq 0$. We usually denote $[I,I]$ by $I^2$.

An ideal $I$ of $L$ is said to be essential if its intersection with any non-zero ideal is again a non-zero ideal.

Comment: Hm, well this is certainly not true for ordinary rings, so I would be interested to see if it works for Lie algebras. Where did you find the problem?

Comment: Unfortunately i’m not handy with Lie algebras, but here is what I wonder: isn’t there a Lie algebra with infinitely many ideals, all of which are linearly ordered? Then the quotient by the intersection of nonzero ideals would be a counterexample.  Maybe this doesn’t work for Lie algebras though.

Comment: I have a hard time imagining non-trivial examples for such a pair $I \subseteq L$ at all (where by "trivial" I mean: $L$ is semisimple and $I =L$). Can you add some examples for $I$ and $L$ as described?

Comment: @rschwieb, I found this problem in LECTURES ON ALGEBRAS OF QUOTIENTS OF LIE ALGEBRAS by Mercedes Siles Molina.

Comment: Torsten Schoeneberg, consider $A$ an associative semiprime algebra and $Z$ its center. It is possible to prove that $A^{(-)}/Z$ is semiprime and for every essential ideal $I$ of $A$, $(I+Z)/Z$ is an essential ideal of $A^{(-)}/Z$. This is a "nontrivial" example. Or do you want a concrete example?

Comment: Yes, some concrete examples would be helpful.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg do you consider the example of $I$ 1-dimensional in a 2-dimensional nonabelian Lie algebra as nontrivial?

Comment: @M.Wolf  I found this link: http://webpersonal.uma.es/~MSILESM/Pub_BST_Esp_files/NotesCRTMay08.pdf, but didn't find the problem there.

Comment: @YCor: I do not see how a two-dimensional Lie algebra would be semiprime.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg sure, a finite-dimensional Lie algebra is semiprime iff it has trivial solvable radical (i.e., in char 0, semisimple). I didn't guess examples of what you requested. Anyway, the example in my answer is semiprime with essential ideals that are not the whole algebra.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $I,J$ be essential ideals, $K$ ideal. Suppose that $I\cap J\cap K=0$. Since $I$ is essential, we have $J\cap K=0$, and in turn, since $J$ is essential, we have $K=0$. This proves that $I\cap J$ is essential (no assumption on $\mathfrak{g}$ was made).

Second, an arbitrary intersection of essential ideals in a semiprime Lie algebra can fail to be essential. Indeed, let $\mathfrak{g}$ have the basis $x$, $(y_n)_{n\ge 0}$ with $[x,y_n]=y_{n+1}$ and $[y_n,y_m]=0$. It is easy to see that the ideals are: 0, the ideal $I_n$ with basis $(y_k:k\ge n)$, and all subspaces containing the derived subalgebra $I_1$. Hence the intersection of any two nonzero ideals is nonzero, which is stronger than semiprime: every nonzero ideal is essential. But the intersection of all nonzero (=essential) ideals is reduced to zero, which is not essential.